# Getting warnings while installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-webpack@1.7.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native@0.49.2 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-beta.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@3.2.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.12.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.0.0-beta requires a peer of webpack@>=2.0.3-beta <3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I'm getting above mentioned warnings while doing npm install. Although, these are just warnings and are not gonna impact application. But, I want to know what is leading to these warnings.

```
I am using npm `version 5.4.2`
node version is 6.11.4 
webpack 2.1.0-beta.22
```

Answer (score 0):

> first of all last 2 warnings are just for those user who are using
>   other than mac.(Even I wasn't able to resolve them)

Now coming to other warnings.

you can either downgrade your `webpack` version or upgrade everything to latest versions.

They are compatible with each other as I have also done that.

In my opinion upgrading all your components is a better way to solve this.

This module will be helpful while upgrading it [npm-check](https://github.com/dylang/npm-check)

Comment: if we run npm check will that give information of what all needs to be update?

Comment: is there any way we can check for the same?

Comment: yes, but you need to install `npm-check` module. There was a link above you can take reference from that